# Need help understanding ms to fps for a Unity animation

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites, frame-rate

I'm trying to create an animation in Unity (2018.1.1f1) and can't understand how to proceed.

I have a 3 sprites which I need to order like so : 1 2 3 2 (then repeat).
The first and third sprites should have a 640ms delay and the second sprite should be 80ms.

[image]

In the animation window, I don't understand how to translate that into fps on the animation timeline.

What sample should I choose and where I need to put each sprites on the timeline to get the 640 and 80ms specified?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Frame rate is a nebulous thing

First thing to understand: the frame *rate* is going to be "however many frames the game can manage in the specified time interval." Typically games try to achieve 60 frames per second, though others aim for 30 for one reason or another.

And any given frame may not occur with the exact same time taken as the previous or the next frame. For example, to achieve 60 frames per second, each frame would need to compute and render in 16.666 milliseconds. But if one frame takes 15, and the next two take 17, then...well, your average across those three frames is 16.666, everything's fine.

Fine, except for your "it has to be exactly 80ms" animation, which would be visible for 4.8 frames, not 5 frames, as that would be 83ms: 3ms too long. You're just going to have to live with this. Also, 80ms is *really short.* I suspect that most people won't even recognize this middle frame unless they actively pay attention to the sprite. Its slow enough to be visible, (ie. below the [Flicker Fusion Threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold)) but too fast to notice at a glance and react to.

In any case, lets look at this window:

[image: Animation window]

The timeline across the right there is timed out in *seconds,* so your animation will start and finish in about a second and a half (1440ms).

So, measuring things out, you want your transition points about here:

[image: Intervals]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was all the help I needed to understand how to make this work. I was able to make all the animations I wanted (running, attacking, getting damage, etc.). Much appreciated!